# Two compnents from two layout with same id

Tags: android, kotlin

I am interesting in problem of two components with same id. For example I need to include two layouts, where I can see different components, but with same id. In **Kotlin** I can access to it by using its **id**. Here we will get an error that states **Overload resolution ambiguity**. So, the question is what should I do in such cases in order to get rid of this error.

Comment: can you show us the layouts ?

Comment: If You can change IDs to prevent duplicates then always do so, aside from `findViewById` problems it can cause `saveState` issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix it like this

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout1.myTextView as myTextView1
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout2.myTextView as myTextView2
```

And then use variable myTextView1 and myTextView2 for respective textviews in layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `import` with layout reference like this

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout-name>.*
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to have two components with the same id.  
Unless **it's absolutely necessary**, I suggest to rename one of them after you check that they're not already used by other resources or code, by right clicking on the id and then `Find Usages`. If you use `Refactor` the changes will be safer.